# msbuild can't find vcproj files specified in solution after I move the whole source tree

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

Having moved my entire source tree from one place to another, msbuild can't seem to build it properly as it's still hanging on to some absolute paths from the old location.  But I can't figure out how!

```
"D:\my_new_path\build_installer.proj" (rebuild target) (1) ->
"D:\my_new_path\build_output.proj" (Rebuild target) (2) ->
"D:\my_new_path\subdir\projectdir\my_solution.sln" (Rebuild target) (3) ->
(my_solution:Rebuild target) ->
  VCBUILD : error : project file 'D:\MY_OLD_PATH\subdir\projectdir\my_project.vcproj'
 was not found or not a valid project file. [D:\my_new_path\subdir\projectdir\my_solution.sln]

1 Error(s)
```

The solution file points to multiple project files in locations that look like relative paths, as they should be e.g

```
Project("{F184B08F-C81C-45F6-A57F-E45ABD9991F28F}") = "one_of_my_projects", "..\one_of_my_projects\one_of_my_projects.vbproj", "{BF412673-C3D3-4757-93D4-C8A772A3B26F8D}"
```

The solution builds fine from within vs2008 and I have tried cleaning it from here too.

I have searched file contents of the source tree for `MY_OLD_PATH` and it is nowhere to be found - so - why is vcbuild still looking for projects on it??

Comment: I hit something like this a while back. Turn on viewing invisible files, and go delete any and every *.suo and *.sdf file you can find. Give me a shout if this solves it and I'll add it as an answer. Edit: I see Hans gave similar advice so I wont try to hijack the rep :P

Comment: @HansPassant it's a vs2008 project

Comment: Got it - it was the .sln.cache file.  Not quite sure why windows explorer search file contents didn't pick this up, but vs find in files did.  Cheers!